# SQL Aggregating Mixed Data

Tags: sql, max, aggregate, min

I have a table that has 3 columns

1. STA (which is equivalent to X)
2. BL (which is equivalent to y)
3. Ultimate_Load (which has positive and negative values)

I want to aggregate column 3 by the maximum of absolute values, but display the actual (negative or positive) value.

your help is appreciated

Comment: Could you provide an example, please?

Comment: What if `Ultimate_Load` have *both* positive and negative values with the *same* absolute value, e.g. `6` and `-6`? What should be value should be returned?

Comment: update you question and provide a proper sample please

Comment: Not clear what are you asking, provide what is your rdbms, db schema, sample data and expected result.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work. You get de max absolute value of ultimate_load and then change it's sign depending on the sign of MAX(ultimate_load)+MIN(ultimate_load).

```
SELECT STA,BL, MAX(ABS(ULTIMATE_LOAD)) * case sign(MAX(ULTIMATE_LOAD)+min(ULTIMATE_LOAD)) when 0 then 1 when -1 then -1 else 1 end as maxvalue
     FROM TAB
    GROUP BY STA, BL
```